# android app not working other than 2.1(works perfectly)

Tags: android, android-version

i have built a app based on 2.1 ..forward compatibility error occuring .Though its not showing any error on logcat still the click events are not working on any later version than android 2.1.On 2.1 it works perfectly.In my manifest i have used uses minsdk=7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new Lint tool include in the ADT of Eclipse. This tool inform you about versions incompatibilities and show you what pieces of code causes crashes when run on, for example, Android 1.6

Eclipse--> Window--> Run android lint --> Your project

Comment: Run Android lint option is not showing anything under it.Unable to see project name.

Comment: On screen 1 there is a image when i click it redirects to another screen which has a button and 3 imageview on imageview click it should open a form.But the onclick listener on this screen is not working none of the onscreen listener. Image of the imageview is from database used php for the server side content

Comment: But the entire app works on 2.1which is where it was developed but on higher versions the onclicklistener is disabled on screen 2. Please help.

Comment: The app is working on android 2.2version as well but after that its not working. Thank you Aracem. If anything more can be added please do tell me.

Answer (score 0):

hello droid you can use like this in manifest.xml like this

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
```

Comment: i am using                                                       uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"    android:targetSdkVersion="15"              android:maxSdkVersion="15"   still using this one.I will inform you.

Comment: this will work for all maxversion change android:targetSdkVersion="15".

Comment: With the changed permission application is closing unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes nikki  that was my idea, explicitly provide support though i know there is a forward compatibility but i have no idea how onclicklistener is not working even though its working on 2.1 and 2.2

Comment: its sorted, actually there was some xml error though it was not showing on logcat. I redid the entirer xml its working now.